# Create a mouse recorder like Clicktale and Crazy Egg

Tags: javascript, mouse, tracking, recording

I want to create my own mouse tracker, like Clicktale and Crazy Egg. Tracking the mouse movements and scrolling shouldn’t be too hard. But what about all changes to the document (HTML, inputs and selects).

Is there an easy way to record all javascript actions on a site. So I can save the actions and later be able to repeat them when I want to replay the visitor’s actions?

Or somehow record all changes that are done to the document (saving the `innerHTML` everytime there is a change is probably not an option).

The recording must be related to time.

When the recording is done there will be an AJAX request that copies the page and insert the new Javascript in to it so it is possible to watch...

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would like to say that even though the task you are describing sounds to be pretty easy, it is actually far more complex when you dig into it. I should know since I've been spending almost 3 years making stuff like this work and work well for my company Ehavior.

You can use the DOM mutation events to monitor changes to the DOM tree. I guess this will give you what you are asking for. You should be aware though, that the mutation events are only available in newer browsers.

Hope this is still helpful to you, even though your question is a little dated :-)